# JSON object as GET query parameter in BigQuery REST API?

Tags: json, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, get

Reading the documentation of a **Google Cloud Platform BigQuery API** https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults it states that the *formatOptions* query parameter is passed as a JSON object with the following JSON structure:

```
{
   "useInt64Timestamp": boolean
}
```

Sending a GET request like `https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{{projectId}}/queries/{{JOBid}}?maxResults=1&formatOptions={"useInt64Timestamp":true}` returns a 400 Bad Request with a response body:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"formatOptions\": Cannot bind query parameter. '**formatOptions**' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types.",
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"formatOptions\": Cannot bind query parameter. 'formatOptions' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types.",
            "reason": "invalid"
        }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

How to send the **formatOptions** object as a GET request parameter, how to encode it so that the BigQuery API recognizes it as valid?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to send the query parameter as follows:

```
https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{{projectId}}/queries/{{jobId}?formatOptions.useInt64Timestamp=True
```